# Open default web browser and read requests being sent

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, request

so I'm trying to create an python program that can basically send api requests to the site that we use to manage homework in my school. The problem with this site is that it not only logs you out after the session expires, it logs you out if you close the tab, or switch apps on mobile, forcing you to go through a rather lengthy sign in process (Unless you just use the url at the final stage to login, but it is lengthy and still not ideal). What its supposed to do is request the homework lists through an api request, and that part works fine. The problem is the authorization tokens, which expire after an hour. I cant figure out how to get the refresh token from the sign in process, so I cant use that to get a new one, so my idea was to open the default browser if the authorization token is expired and direct it to the google login page. When the user logs in by clicking their account, the browser sends a POST request to the homework site which contains the auth token. I'm trying to then intercept that request, close the browser and then I can use that token for the next hour. If theres a way to get a refresh token instead that would be even better, but I cant find anything on how to intercept it.